# Increase the waiting time for ReverseProxy

Tags: go

My client is  using ReverseProxy to call another service that service takes maximum of 60 seconds to respond to my request. But my client is waiting for only 30-35 seconds. I need to increase the waiting time 60 seconds. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably using the [`DefaultTransport`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper) (default timeout is 30 seconds)

[`Transport` for proxy request needs to be set.](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy)

Try adding something like this for setting timeout:

```
reverseproxy.Transport=&http.Transport{
    Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
    DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
        Timeout:   60 * time.Second,
        KeepAlive: 60 * time.Second,
        DualStack: true,
    }).DialContext,
    MaxIdleConns:          100,
    IdleConnTimeout:       90 * time.Second,
    TLSHandshakeTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
    ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
}
```

Comment: Increased the Timeout and  KeepAlive to 60 seconds , still not working

Comment: @avinash show some code so people here may help you

Answer (score 0):

```
proxy.Transport = &http.Transport{
    ResponseHeaderTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
}
```

That's enough